# Array filtering with multiple conditions javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to filter an array with multiple conditions. I have a search filter form with 2 select, 1 checkboxes fieldset and 1 radio button fieldset. I have functions that return items that match chosen conditions. They work only separately. What is the best approach to find objects that match all conditions?

I tried to make if statements for all possible options, but code doesn't work correctly and it looks like there should be some better options to do so.

Here is function examples:

```js
    function chooseRating(hotel) {
      return hotel.rating == e.target.value;
    }

    function chooseMeal(hotel) {
      return hotel.mealType == e.target.value;
    }


    function choosePlace(hotel)  {
      for (let l = 0; l < chosenPlace.length; l++) {
      if(chosenPlace[l].checked) {
        return hotel.region == e.target.value;
      }
              }
    }
```

How should I filter the array with that?

```js
  let filteredCards = hotels.filter(function(hotel, index, hotels) {
    // ??
  });
```

[image: Screenshot]

User chooses his requirements for hotel and he should get hotels, that match all requirements. And if some of them not chosen, then they are don't count by default.

Comment: Please add input and output that you expect.

Comment: Those functions won't work without an `e`, but that event is a one time thing and you rather need the `value` of the `<input>`.

Comment: @shubham-gupta I gave some additional information. Is this what you asked for?

Comment: @chris-g I was using values at first, but it didn't work correctly also

Comment: Can you provide some HTML as well?

Comment: @ibrahim-mahrir  the whole form? Or just one select for example?

Comment: Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/fg4p85h7/

Comment: @chris-g thank you very much! Looks exactly what I needed

Answer (score 16):

You can chain your `filter()` calls, like this:

```
// first filter
function filterRating(hotel) {
  return hotel.rating >= filters.rating;
}

// second filter
function filterMeal(hotel) {
  return !filters.mealType.length || hotel.mealType == filters.mealType;
}

// apply both filters to initial array
function update() {
  let filteredCards = hotels.filter(filterRating).filter(filterMeal);
};
```

Full example:

```js
var filters = {
  rating: 4,
  mealType: ""
};

rating.value = filters.rating;
mealtype.value = filters.mealType;

rating.addEventListener("input", function() {
  filters.rating = rating.value;
  update();
});
mealtype.addEventListener("input", function() {
  filters.mealType = mealtype.value;
  update();
});

function filterRating(hotel) {
  return hotel.rating >= filters.rating;
}

function filterMeal(hotel) {
  return !filters.mealType.length || hotel.mealType == filters.mealType;
}

function update() {
  let filteredCards = getHotels().filter(filterRating).filter(filterMeal);
  console.log(filters);
  output.innerHTML = filteredCards.map(hotel => `<span>${hotel.name}</span>`).join("");
};
update();

function getHotels() {
  return [{
      name: "A",
      rating: 5,
      mealType: "full"
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      rating: 4,
      mealType: "full"
    },
    {
      name: "C",
      rating: 4,
      mealType: "breakfast"
    },
    {
      name: "D",
      rating: 5,
      mealType: "breakfast"
    }
  ];
}
```

```css
input,
select {
  margin: 1em 0
}

#rating {
  width: 3em
}

#output span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
Rating &gt;= <input id="rating" value="5" type="number"><br> Meal:
<select id="mealtype">
  <option value="">any</option>
  <option>breakfast</option>
  <option>full</option>
</select><br>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831651/javascript-filter-array-multiple-conditions

Answer (score 6):

**A clean and functional solution**

```
const combineFilters = (...filters) => (item) => {
    return filters.map((filter) => filter(item)).every((x) => x === true);
};
```

then you use it like so:

```
const filteredArray = arr.filter(combineFilters(filterFunc1, filterFunc2));
```

and filterFunc1 for example might look like this:

```
const filterFunc1 = (item) => {
  return item === 1 ? true : false;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood the problem correctly, you can just pass all your matching functions to the `filter()` test function and require them all to be truthy using AND operators:

```
let filteredCards = hotels.filter(hotel => chooseRating(hotel) && chooseMeal(hotel) && choosePlace(hotel))
```

This is the same as:

```
let filteredCards = hotels.filter(hotel => {
  return chooseRating(hotel) && chooseMeal(hotel) && choosePlace(hotel)
})
```

This is also the same:

```
let filteredCards = hotels.filter(function(hotel) {
  return chooseRating(hotel) && chooseMeal(hotel) && choosePlace(hotel)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

So lets say you have something like this:

```
<select id="rating">Rating options here ...</select>
<select id="meals">Meals options here ...</select>

<fieldset id="places">
<input type="checkbox" value="one">place one</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="two">place two</input>
</fieldset>

<input type="radio" name="rad" value="rad_one">radio one</input>
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="rad_two">radio two</input>
```

You can filter the hotels Array with something like:

```
let selected_rating = document.querySelector('#rating').value;
let selected_meal = document.querySelector('#meals').value;
let selected_places = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('#places input[type="checkbox"]:checked'),function(elem){ return elem.value});
let selected_radio = document.querySelector('[name="rad"]:checked').value;

let filteredCards = hotels.filter(function(hotel){
    return hotel.rating == selected_rating
        && hotel.mealType == selected_meal
        && selected_places.indexOf(hotel.place) != -1
        && hotel.region == selected_radio;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a filter for a code challenge using 2 inputs.

My first approach as you said was writing the if conditions inside one filter and didn't work.

What I did was create a new array filtering by the first condition, and then filter that returned array using the second condition and that worked.

Hope this solves your problem :D

Comment: I think it could be possible only with the specific order of filters, that can't be changed. Here, for example, user can choose region first and only then mealtype and vice versa :)

Comment: The order doesn't matter.

Comment: As Chris says, the order doesn't matter, if you first filter by the first input and the user didnt change anything, you'll get the same array and then filter using the second input.