# JavaScript - Array item not being found

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

For some reason, the result here is coming up as false, yet the array contains that particular dateId.

See code below:

```
var pollOptions = [
  {"dateId": "183738", "answer": false},
  {"dateId": "183738", "answer": true}
];

var theDate = "183738";
var doesDateExist = theDate in pollOptions


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = doesDateExist;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` operator works for objects (not on arrays). You can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to check the presence of a specific value in an array of objects:

```js
var pollOptions = [
  {"dateId": "183738", "answer": false},
  {"dateId": "183738", "answer": true}
];

var theDate = "183738";
var doesDateExist = pollOptions.some(({ dateId }) => dateId === theDate);


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = doesDateExist;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect :)
If i wanted to get the "answer" value from the key I am searching for, how woild I do this?

Comment: @DarrylBartlett You mean you will have this type of code? `theAnswer = false`

Comment: @Mohammed Usman - Yeah that's right. So if I was searching for 183738, it would return the answer, for example false.

Comment: @DarrylBartlett If you wants to find object with multiple search filters, you can check this post... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831651/javascript-filter-array-multiple-conditions

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.includes()` method on an array rather an **in**`, which works on objects.

```js
var pollOptions = [{"dateId": "183738", "answer": false}, {"dateId": "183738", "answer": true}];

var theDate = "183738";
var doesDateExist = pollOptions.map(item => item.dateId).includes(theDate);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = doesDateExist;
```

Additionally, I use the `.map()` function to stream your object into an array only containing the dateIds. Then we can use `.includes()`

Comment: How could I get the "answer" out of this query as well?

Comment: What do you mean? it returns true / false as you specifed

Answer (score 1):

```js
var pollOptions = [{"dateId": "183738", "answer": false}, {"dateId": "183738", "answer": true}];
var theDate = "183738";

var doesDateExist  = Boolean(pollOptions.find(function(item) {
   return item.dateId === theDate
}))

console.log(doesDateExist )
```