# Filter through different categories and return multiple entries

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating a simple app where I want to filter the list of hardcoded employees based on different categories.
This is my employees class:

```
export class Emp{
    eid:number
    name:string
    department:string
    age:number
    skills:number
}
```

I have created a search box in html such that user can search either by entering name or dept or eid of an employee and get the details of respective employee. For example

```
employees:Emp[]=[
    {eid:1,name:"Vikram",age:29,department:"HTML5",skills:5},
    {eid:5,name:"Vetaal",age:28,department:"CSS",skills:2.5},]
```

Now if a user searches for 5 then he should get the details of both these employees since 5 being in HTML5 and EID.

This is the logic I am using:

```
export class EmpDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  private _eidfilter:string;
  get eidfilter():string {
    return this._eidfilter
  }
  set eidfilter(value : string){
    this._eidfilter=value
    this.filteredemp=this.performfilter(value.toString());
  }

  filteredemp:Emp[]=[];

performfilter(filterBy:string): Emp[] {
      filterBy=filterBy.toLowerCase()
      return this.employees.filter((employee:Emp)=>employee.eid.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterBy)),this.employees.filter((employee:Emp)=>employee.department.toLowerCase().includes(filterBy))
    }
```

The problem I am facing is that whatever I return second in performfilter function only that is being shown in the required list for example if I code : `return <<department>> , <<eid>>` then it returns on the basis of eid only

Comment: You can't just pass multiple functions separated by comma to `filter()`; the expression `a, b` evaluates to `b` so your code will ignore the first filter. You need to use a single function and check all properties inside. Basically: `....filter(emp => cond1 || cond2 || cond3)`

Comment: Sorry, I was correct in a way but got the details wrong. In function call arguments, the comma doesn't behave that way; the first function gets used, the second is ignored here. Anyway, if it worked, feel free to delete the question.

Comment: Duplicate: [javascript filter array multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831651/javascript-filter-array-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Use OR condition in your `filter()` method

```
performfilter(filterBy: string): Emp[] {
    filterBy = filterBy.toLowerCase()
    return this.employees.filter((employee: Emp) => employee.eid.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterBy) || employee.department.toLowerCase().includes(filterBy))
}
```

Comment: There's no need to answer duplicates; please check for those before posting an answer.