# How can I filter based on multiple values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, filter

How can I filter based on multiple values in Javascript.

I want to make a frontend filter in react where all value is a select field except name its a search Input.

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "anna",
    group: "group 1",
    house: "green",
    subject: "math"
  },
  {
    name: "mike",
    group: "group 2",
    house: "blue",
    subject: "science"
  },
  {
    name: "mike",
    group: "group 2",
    house: "blue",
    subject: "physics"
  },
  {
    name: "holly",
    group: "group 1",
    house: "green",
    subject: "chemistry"
  }
]
```

Expectation:

1. selecting "group 1" and "green" should result in

```
[
  {
    name: "anna",
    group: "group 1",
    house: "green",
    subject: "math"
  },
  {
    name: "holly",
    group: "group 1",
    house: "green",
    subject: "chemistry"
  }
]
```

2. selecting "mike", "group 2" and "blue" should result in

```
[
  {
    name: "mike",
    group: "group 2",
    house: "blue",
    subject: "science"
  },
  {
    name: "mike",
    group: "group 2",
    house: "blue",
    subject: "physics"
  }
]
```

3. Selecting nothing should render whole array

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far yourself?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I tried using .filter() with & and | conditions. Didn't worked.

Comment: Part of the contract here on SO is showing your own work.  That's why you see comments like mine.  Next time, even if it's not working, show the best effort you've made so far and explain what it's not doing properly, and you will likely get better and quicker answers.

Comment: The answer I was writing before this was (properly) closed as a duplicate is now posted on [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69306883).  I think it offers two separate useful APIs.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
data.filter(x=>x.group=='group 1'&& x.house=="green")
```

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "anna",
    group: "group 1",
    house: "green",
    subject: "math"
  },
  {
    name: "mike",
    group: "group 2",
    house: "blue",
    subject: "science"
  },
  {
    name: "mike",
    group: "group 2",
    house: "blue",
    subject: "physics"
  },
  {
    name: "holly",
    group: "group 1",
    house: "green",
    subject: "chemistry"
  }
]

var result = data.filter(x=>x.group=='group 1'&& x.house=="green")
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I don't really think that OP has requested filtering by this particular properties with these particular values. I would rather assume that their intention was **arbitrary** subset (including empty one) of properties and values. (and it wasn't mine downvote, just in case)

Comment: according to his last comment I thought that he is using bitwise and and bitwise or. That's why I given this answer. That is what I thought.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "anna",
    group: "group 1",
    house: "green",
    subject: "math"
  },
  {
    name: "mike",
    group: "group 2",
    house: "blue",
    subject: "science"
  },
  {
    name: "mike",
    group: "group 2",
    house: "blue",
    subject: "physics"
  },
  {
    name: "holly",
    group: "group 1",
    house: "green",
    subject: "chemistry"
  }
];

function filterArr(v1='', v2='', v3='', v4=''){

  return data.filter(f=>{
    return (f.name).includes(v1) && (f.group).includes(v2) && (f.house).includes(v3) && (f.subject).includes(v4);
  });

}

let arr = filterArr('mike', 'group 2');

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Man, you'd go in lots of troubles if there were few dozens of fields in that table (and it wasn't mine downvote, just in case)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov 
This example is not about hundreds of fields, but only four, which is why I wrote this example

Comment: Did you happen to hear about loops?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov
What is it? are you having a bad day?

Comment: Mate, it's totally the opposite - I had a lot of fun, especially during the last 20 minutes. Really, I'm trying to deliver here one simple message (with a bit of joke, though): your code is rigid and for a table of few dozens fields it will look ridiculously clunky. I don't even try to be offensive here, trust me :)

Comment: Consider something, like this as an example of what I am talking about: `const multiFilter=(arr,obj)=>arr.filter(_obj=>Object.keys(obj).every(key=>_obj[key].toLowerCase().includes(obj[key].toLowerCase())))`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov
If the question had been about hundreds of data, I would have written differently