# javascript how to filter array for multiple condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the filter:

```
var filter = {
  address: ['England'],
  name: ['Mark', 'Tom'] // Mark or Tom in this case
};
```

```
var users = [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'johnson@mail.com',
    age: 25,
    address: 'USA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    email: 'tom@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'England'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    email: 'mark@mail.com',
    age: 28,
    address: 'England'
  }
];
```

The filtered result should be

```
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    email: 'tom@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'England'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    email: 'mark@mail.com',
    age: 28,
    address: 'England'
  }
```

Comment: Already asked, and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831651/javascript-filter-array-multiple-conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take your `users`, filter it, and see if the name is contained in the filters.

```
const onlyMarkAndTom = users.filter(user => filter.name.includes(user.name))
```

Include additional conditions to narrow down the result

```
const onlyMarkAndTom = users.filter(user => filter.name.includes(user.name) && ...)
```

Comment: I also need to filter `address` at the same time

Comment: Same logic, include additional conditions to the filter. `&& ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
users.filter((user) => {
  if (!filter.address.includes(user.address)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!filter.name.includes(user.name)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to be substantially different from the accepted one.

Comment: No. But the early-return style is easier to extend for multiple filtering conditions.